# What's the meaning of "be tended on horseback"?

Tags: meaning

Could you please explain what the meaning of *"be tended on horseback"* is?

The text is here:

> When Grandpa-down-the-hill was a young man, there’d been herds of
>   livestock spread across the mountain, and they were tended on horseback.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...**there had been herds of livestock spread across the mountain, and they** [the livestock] **were tended** [that is, *cared for*] **on horseback.**

NOAD defines *tend* as:

> **tend** (*verb*) care for or look after

So, what that sentence means is:

> ...**there had been herds of livestock spread across the mountain, and they** (the cattle) **were tended** [by men on] **on horseback.**

In other words: **people riding on horses looked after the livestock.**

Answer (score 0):

You could have found these things out in a short time by using a dictionary, either printed or online. When Grandpa-down-the-hill was a young man, the cattle spread across the mountain were cared for by people riding on horses. Have you heard of "cowboys" or seen any "Western" cinema films?

> cattle noun [ plural ] UK ​  /ˈkæt.əl/ US ​  /ˈkæt̬.əl/ ​ B1 cows and
>   bulls that are kept for their milk or meat:
>
> beef/dairy cattle

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cattle

> tend verb (CARE) ​ [ T ] formal to care for something or someone:
>
> He carefully tended his sunflower plants. The nurse gently tended the
>   patient's cuts and bruises.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tend

> horseback noun UK ​  /ˈhɔːs.bæk/ US ​  /ˈhɔːrs.bæk/ on horseback ​
>   riding a horse:
>
> police on horseback

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/horseback